# Probability based on Observed Data

Tags: probability, self-study, philosophical

I'm trying to figure if my reasoning and application of probability is correct in this made up example using R. Example data:

```
A = c(34.5, 34.2, 35, 35.1, 36, 35.2, 35.7, 34.8, 34.9, 34.4)
B = c(35, 34.2, 36, 35, 34, 34.2, 34.2, 34.5, 34.4)
```

Let's assume 2 groups (A and B) we sampled some particular measure of interest. Traditional Frequentist approach would be to apply a t-test, given 2 variables and we want to know the probability of observing a difference larger than the one we got, assuming the null-hypothesis is true, and if we were to sample an infinite # of times.

```
t.test(A,B)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  A and B
t = 1.3423, df = 16.183, p-value = 0.198
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2131596  0.9509374
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 34.98000  34.61111
```

Simple, but doesn't say much about my observed data. So where I'm stuck mathematically and philosophically is looking at the probability, given the data, of someone in group A having a larger measured value than someone in group B. Because this is 2 groups, I can't do a pre & post comparison. So I used the `outer()` function for this comparison:

```
outer(A,B,">")
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Basically running every possible comparison, asking if A > B, between the 2 groups. If I apply the `mean()` to this:

```
mean(outer(A,B,">"))
[1] 0.6666667
```

I get a probability 66.67%, that someone in group A will have a measured value higher than someone in group B.

My question, is this mathematically appropriate (doing all comparisons)? and if possible on this SE, philosophically reasonable? Again, I'm only speaking of observables, not "possible" long runs, and only possible interpretation given my collected (observed) data. I know the conclusions could change if I collected more data, especially with such a small sample size. I wanted to know if I was in trouble either mathematically or philosophically speaking.

Edit:

Another way of saying what I wrote above is P(A-B>0). I could also ask the P(A-B>x), where x could be a # of interest or relevant to the field. Example:

```
mean(outer(A,B,"-")>0.5)
[1] 0.4555556
```

Where P(A-B>0.5) = 45.56%. Numbers are of course very close, and still up to a user to decide if this is useful for their applications or not.

Comment: Your calculation of the proportion of cases where $A>B$ and if you also count 1/2 for ties, the result is simply a scaled version of the usual Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney statistic, i.e. you're calculating $\frac{U}{n_1n_2}$

Comment: Your ideas are already established. An article that might interest you is by Vargha on measuring stochastic dominance https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240802102_A_Critique_and_Improvement_of_the_CL_Common_Language_Effect_Size_Statistics_of_McGraw_and_Wong. If you account for ties, `mean(outer(A, B, ">")) + .5 * mean(outer(A, B, "=="))`, you arrive at Vargha's A; advantage being that if you swap A and B in the syntax, new result plus old result add up to 1. You could take the difference between both numbers and arrive at Cliff's delta (stochastic difference).

Answer (score 3):

$t$-test compares means of the two samples, but this doesn't mean that means are the only thing that we can compare. You can define your test statistics in terms of probability that any value of A is greater then any value of B (I am not discussing in here if it is valid in your particular case or not, as this may depend on your particular problem), however this is not a test yet!

If you want to conduct a hypothesis test, you need to check what would be the probability of observing the result that from your sample *if it came from the null distribution*. In terms of your data, the simple nonparametric test you could conduct is the permutation test, where you would mix your two samples together, shuffle them, and then draw the two samples from the shuffled data. By doing so, you would simulate the situation where each of the observations could have been assigned to any of the two groups, i.e. the group assignment would be "random" and should not affect the result of comparison between the groups. By conducting many such simulations, you would obtain a "null distribution" of the test statistic of your choice calculated on the simulated data. Next, you would compare the test statistic calculated on your actual data to the null distribution to see *what would be the probability of observing your result if the group assignment played no role*.

Notice however that if you wanted to test the hypothesis that

> a randomly selected value from one sample will be less than or greater
>   than a randomly selected value from a second sample

there already is the [Mann–Whitney $U$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) that does exactly this.

```r
set.seed(123)

A <- c(34.5, 34.2, 35, 35.1, 36, 35.2, 35.7, 34.8, 34.9, 34.4)
B <- c(35, 34.2, 36, 35, 34, 34.2, 34.2, 34.5, 34.4)
AB <- c(A, B)

k <- length(A)
n <- length(AB)

Tstat <- function(x) {
  A <- x[1:k]
  B <- x[(k+1):n]
  mean(outer(A,B,">"))
}

Tstat_sim <- replicate(50000, Tstat(sample(AB)))

mean(Tstat(AB) <= Tstat_sim)
## [1] 0.07672
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, it doesn't answer my question entirely. I'm not interested in null-hypothesis testing, only in what my collected data says (not long range runs). My question was about formation of Probability based on the collected data only, with the conditions, assumptions, and possible errors in the way it was collected, and see what conclusion(s) the data logically entails.

Comment: @Kunio based "only on your collected data" the proportion of elements such that A > B is what you calculated. There is no probability involved if you want to talk about "only the collected data". You could talk about probabilities either in frequentist setting ("long range runs") or Bayesian (how certain does the data make you about the conclusion).